# How to extract localstorage values in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using form in reactjs. I stored user data in localstorage now I want to upload file and i want to store file key with userID which is already stored in localstorage. With `localstorage.getItem('user')` I am able to show user values but did not use in key, when i display user values in console it give me message with undefined. Could you please help me how i can set key with userid.

**Code**

```
    handleUpload = e => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const storeUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    reader.onload = function(upload) {
      fetch(`http://...../s3/uploadtoaws`, {
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          userId: storeUser._id,
          type: 'employee',
          content: upload.target.result,
          key: this.userId,
          oldKey: '',
        }),
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(res => {
          console.warn(res);
        })
        .done();
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(e.file.originFileObj);
  };
```

Comment: Are you storing user to the localStorage as an object?

Comment: Where you have `key: this.userId`, the `this` refers to the `reader`, not the object literal you are in the middle of defining. Just use `key: storeUser._id` (note that your question title is very misleading, this question isn't about reading localStorage in any way. it also has zero to do with React)

Comment: Yes, I am storing user to localstorge

Comment: @ChrisG Thank You it working. and i am also want to generate random number with userID. Is it possible

Comment: @Brad Sure, there's `Math.random()` for one.

Answer (score 0):

Use window object to store your data if it is in-incentive

Like,

// Store like this..
window.user = {"_id": 1, "userName": "Bhavin00"};

// Use like this..
console.log(window.user);

or you can use npm package like :- [reactjs-localstorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactjs-localstorage)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

const { id: userId } = user;
```

Now you can use `userId` in the above request you shared.